# Deinterlace a vector using vDSP

Tags: ios, swift, accelerate-framework, vdsp

Let's say I have a vector:

```swift
let input: [Float] = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, ...]
```

What I'd like to do is deinterlace this vector by selecting every other value to produce 2 new vectors as output, as follows:

```
[1, 3, 5, 7, ...]
[2, 4, 6, 8, ...]
```

What's the best way to do this in [vDSP](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/accelerate/vdsp?language=objc)?

Comment: Are your values really integers, or are they Floats or Doubles?

Comment: They are floats - updated for clarity

Comment: Use `vDSP_ctoz`. (If you need it written up as actual code, I can do that later, but if you're familiar with vDSP already, it should be straightforward.)

Comment: Actually, I forgot it's easier now: look at DSPSplitComplex.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'm familiar with parts of vDSP, but not complex vectors...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The tool you want here is `vDSP.convert(interleavedComplexVector:toSplitComplexVector:)`. Don't let the "complex vector" confuse you. It doesn't matter if these are "complex" or not. An "interleaved complex vector" is just "a series of even and odd values." And a "split complex vector" is just "a struct containing a list of evens and a list of odds." These are sometimes interpreted as real and imaginary components, but that interpretation has nothing to do with how `convert` works (and often has nothing to do with how these values are used in practice).

So assuming a `[Float]` like:

```
let input: [Float] = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

And two output lists ("vectors") like:

```
var evens: [Float] = Array(repeating: 0, count: input.count / 2)
var odds = evens
```

You can split them up this way:

```
evens.withUnsafeMutableBufferPointer { evenPtr in
    odds.withUnsafeMutableBufferPointer { oddPtr in

        var split = DSPSplitComplex(realp: evenPtr.baseAddress!,
                                    imagp: oddPtr.baseAddress!)

        input.withUnsafeBytes {
            vDSP.convert(interleavedComplexVector: Array($0.bindMemory(to: DSPComplex.self)),
                         toSplitComplexVector: &split)
        }
    }
}

// At this point, evens and odds are filled in.
```

This is intentionally modeled closely on [Apple's example code](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/accelerate/finding_the_component_frequencies_in_a_composite_sine_wave) for setting up an FFT.

If you happen to need more values split up this way (particularly 4 values), take a look at `vImageConvert_ARGBFFFFtoPlanarF` and related functions. Just like "complex" really just means "two floats," "ARGBFFFF" just means "4 floats." Numbers are just numbers and sometimes the function you need happens to be named based on another use case.